# Am I using commas incorrectly?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

I’m writing a story in Google docs, and on certain sentences its automatic grammar checker suggests that I remove a comma. Here are some examples.

> Have you been eating enough, lately?

> I must go, now.

Those sentences seem confusing/incorrect if I remove the commas, especially the first one. I’ve read the rules of comma usage on a few different websites, but I can’t seem to find a something that addresses my issue.

Comment: There isn't a definite answer. In my *opinion* the first sentence is fine with or without the comma depending on the intended vibe. The comma in the second sentence sounds wrong; depending on intended emphasis I would remove it or replace it with a dash or full stop.

Comment: This is really a style question. Strictly speaking, neither one requires a comma and I would say neither benefits from a comma.

Comment: The confusion may originate from the fact that as introductory words or phrases, these would most often be offset by commas: "Lately, have you been eating enough?" "Now, I must go."